# How to hide a field in Sitecore WFFM

Tags: wffm

How to hide the field in Sitecore WFFM 8.1 upgrade 3?

How to send the values to hidden fields programatically in C#?

Comment: additional note if that helps: you can configure wffm to populate fields using values that comes from url query string parameters

Answer (score 1):

Create a custom field like this:

```cs
public class MyHiddenField : Sitecore.Forms.Mvc.ViewModels.Fields.SingleLineTextField
    {
        public override void Initialize()
        {
            Visible = false;
            Value = "myvalue";
            base.Initialize();
        }
    }
```

So you override the `SingleLineTextField` and:

- set the `Visible` property to false
- assign the `Value` property to .. whatever you want

Comment: Hi @Gatogordo .can we hide the field from sitecore interface?

Comment: You could add such functionality by implementing a property as done here: http://www.sitecorecoffee.com/2016/06/wffm-creating-custom-hidden-field-with.html